# Unknown tag (c:if) warning in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, taglib

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: Lightgrey;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sample Page</h1><br>
  <h3>Admin</h3>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  **<c:set var="isAllowed" value="${false}" />
  <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        <sec:authorize access="hasAuthority('PERMISSION_MANAGER')" var="isAllowed" />
  </sec:authorize>**

  <c:if test="${isAllowed}">
      <h3>Manager</h3>
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab1/search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab1/add">Add</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/sample/tab1/delete">Delete</a></li>
      </ul>
  </c:if>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code am getting unknown tag warning.I have included jstl jar files in WEB-INF/lib directory.Because highlighted block of code only shows this warning.I can't find my mistake.please help.

The JSTL core & security tag library is included at the top of jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

And included jstl jar in maven dependency. But still i am getting warning message as **Unknown tag** for all jstl tag in eclipse. Can some one help me to avoid those warning in jsp page for all jstl tag?

Thanks

**Update:**

```
       <properties>
            <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
            <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <properties>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Post `pom.xml` dependencies.

Comment: Added pom entry with original post. @tarashypka

Comment: So it works fine when you ignore Eclipse's warnings and just run it? And thus this is an Eclipse problem and not a JSP/JSTL problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Eclipse problem. I tried restarting eclipse, but it didn't help.

Finally, i just ignored Eclipse's warning for "Unknown tag" and re-enabled it. And now everything looks good. Only real warning is shown now.

Eclipse-->Windows-->Preferences-->Web-->HTML files-->Validation